# La instrucción no devolvió un conjunto de resultados

Tags: java, jdbc

Tengo mi siguiente codigo el cual inserta una nueva persona con nombre, apellido y edad a una base de datos en SQLServer

```
public void agregarPersona()
    {

        String cadena = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Persona";
        String usuario = "mi_usuario";
        String contrasenia = "mi_contrasenia";

        try
        {
            Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection(cadena, usuario, contrasenia);

            String nombre = txtNombre.getText();
            String apellido = txtApellido.getText();
            int edad = Integer.parseInt(txtEdad.getText());

            String insertar = ("INSERT INTO Personas (nombre,apellido,edad) VALUES ('"+nombre+"','"+apellido+"',"+edad+");");

            PreparedStatement pstm = cn.prepareStatement(insertar);
            ResultSet rs = pstm.executeQuery();

        }catch (SQLException e)
        {
            System.out.println("ERROR AL INSERTAR DATO: " + e);
        }

    }
```

El problema que tengo es que me inserta el dato pero a la vez me salta la excepción del catch la cual dice "La instrucción no devolvió un conjunto de resultados"
Buscando encontré que al realizar una inserción y lanzarla como executeQuery, la inserción no devolverá un ResultSet, por lo tanto se produce ese error, por lo que probe cambiando la linea de mi ResultSet por una de estas

```
ResultSet rs = pstm.execute();
ResultSet rs = pstm.executeUpdate();
```

Pero en este caso me arroja un error de incompatibilidad ya que un booleano no puede ser convertido en un ResultSet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En realidad, tu código está bien al usar `PreparedStatement`. En realidad, esa es la interfaz que necesitas para agregar parámetros para tus consultas. Tal como dices, el problema es que intentabas obtener un `ResultSet` cuando tu SQL es para una operación `INSERT`, por lo que debes cambiar el método. Además, deberías siempre **cerrar la conexión** a la base de datos, esto lo puedes hacer manualmente en un bloque `finally` o usando `try-with-resources` de Java 7 o superior.

Tu código, corregido para soportar parámetros y no concatenar el query, debería lucir así:

```
public void agregarPersona() {

    String cadena = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Persona";
    String usuario = "mi_usuario";
    String contrasenia = "mi_contrasenia";

    //los parámetros se indican con signo de interrogación `?`
    String insertar = "INSERT INTO Personas (nombre,apellido,edad) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
    //try-with-resources va a cerrar los recursos por ti automáticamente
    //en este caso, son 2 recursos por cerrar, la conexión y el PreparedStatement
    try (Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection(cadena, usuario, contrasenia);
         PreparedStatement pstm = cn.prepareStatement(insertar);) {

        String nombre = txtNombre.getText();
        String apellido = txtApellido.getText();
        int edad = Integer.parseInt(txtEdad.getText());

        //colocamos los parámetros del query preparado
        //siempre empiezan en índice 1
        pstm.setString(1, nombre);
        pstm.setString(2, apellido);
        pstm.setInt(3, edad);
        pstm.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR AL INSERTAR DATO.");
        //siempre imprime el stacktrace completo, no solo el mensaje
        //así tendrás más detalles del problema y cómo solucionarlo
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Luiggi! Supongo que a tu código, al final del try, puede cerrar la conexión con cn.close() . Es así como nos han enseñado en la facultad.

Comment: @LucasDavid el `try-with-resources` llama a `Connection#close` automáticamente. No es necesario escribirlo. Si lo usas de la forma que muestras en la pregunta, deberías agregar `finally { if (cn != null) try { cn.close() } catch (SQLException ex) { /* nada */ } }`

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

El error radica en que ResultSet no se usa para realizar un INSERT. Por lo que lo borre de mi código y agregue un Statement que es quien realiza el INSERT. El código me quedo de la siguiente forma

```
public void agregarPersona()
    {

        String cadena = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Persona";
        String usuario = "mi_usuario";
        String contrasenia = "mi_contrasenia";

        try
        {
            Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection(cadena, usuario, contrasenia);
            Statement st = cn.createStatement();

            String nombre = txtNombre.getText();
            String apellido = txtApellido.getText();
            int edad = Integer.parseInt(txtEdad.getText());

            String insertar = ("INSERT INTO Personas (nombre,apellido,edad) VALUES ('"+nombre+"','"+apellido+"',"+edad+");");

            int elementosInsertados = st.executeUpdate(insertar);

        }catch (SQLException e)
        {
            System.out.println("ERROR AL INSERTAR DATO: " + e);
        }

    }
```

Y funciona perfectamente.